# How to remove a character from every string in a list, based on the position where a specific character occurs in the first member of said list?

Tags: python, string

So I have a list of strings, all with the same length, like this:

```py
list_strings=["A-C-TG--","ATCGTAGC","ATGCGATC","ATGCGGTC"]
```

What I'm trying to do is, for each position where the first member of `list_strings` has a "-", remove every character in those same positions from every member of `list_strings`.

My output would be something like this:

```py
new_list_strings=["ACTG","ACTA","AGGA","AGGG"]
```

I've tried doing this:

1. Creating an empty new list.
2. Getting the positions where the first member of `list_strings` has a "-".
3. Remove the gap from all the strings and append the new string to "new_list_strings"

```
list_strings=["A-C-TG--","ATCGTAGC","ATGCGATC","ATGCGGTC"]
new_list_strings=[]
positions=[i for i, letter in enumerate(list_strings[0]) if letter == "-"]
for string in list_strings:
    for i in range(len(string)):
        for pos in positions:
            if i==pos:
                string2=string[:i]+string[i+1:]
                new_list_strings.append(string2)
```

Unfortunately, this is only removing on one of the positions and not all of them. Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I recommend putting a print statement inside your `for pos in positions` loop to see what's happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution using `zip()`

```py
>>> shortened = [*zip(*[t for t in zip(*list_strings) if t[0] != "-"])]
>>> shortened
[('A', 'C', 'T', 'G'), ('A', 'C', 'T', 'A'), ('A', 'G', 'G', 'A'), ('A', 'G', 'G', 'G')]
>>>
>>> new_strings = ["".join(t) for t in shortened]
>>> new_strings
['ACTG', 'ACTA', 'AGGA', 'AGGG']
```

So, there are plenty of ways to do this, but this particular method zips the gene strings together and filters out the tuples which start with a `"-"`. Think of stacking the four gene strings on top of each other: `zip()` takes the "columns" of that stack:

```py
>>> [*zip(*list_strings)]
[('A', 'A', 'A', 'A'), ('-', 'T', 'T', 'T'), ('C', 'C', 'G', 'G'), ('-', 'G', 'C', 'C'), ('T', 'T', 'G', 'G'), ('G', 'A', 'A', 'G'), ('-', 'G', 'T', 'T'), ('-', 'C', 'C', 'C')]
```

After removing the tuples that start with `"-"`, the tuples are zipped back together the other way (think now of taking these tuples and stacking them vertically, then in the same way as before, `zip()` takes the columns of that stack). Finally, `"".join()` turns the tuples of characters into strings.

### "What am I doing wrong?"

To answer the question "what am I doing wrong?", I've added print statements to your code. Try running this and interpreting the output:

```py
list_strings=["A-C-TG--","ATCGTAGC","ATGCGATC","ATGCGGTC"]
new_list_strings=[]
positions=[i for i, letter in enumerate(list_strings[0]) if letter == "-"]

for string in list_strings:
    print(f"string: {string}")
    for i in range(len(string)):
        print(f"    i: {i}")
        for pos in positions:
            print(f"        pos: {pos}")
            if i==pos:
                string2=string[:i]+string[i+1:]
                print(f"            match! string2 result: {string2}")
                new_list_strings.append(string2)
    print()
```

Notice that for each `string`, multiple `string2` objects are created.

### Solution using a plain-Jane accumulator pattern

The barebones accumulator pattern *does* work for this problem:

```py
list_strings = ["A-C-TG--","ATCGTAGC","ATGCGATC","ATGCGGTC"]
positions = [i for i, letter in enumerate(list_strings[0]) if letter == "-"]

new_list_strings = []
for string in list_strings:
    new_str = ""
    for idx, char in string:
        if idx not in positions:
            new_str += char
    new_list_strings.append(new_str)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, great answer, I have a really hard time with python. With the print statements you added I see that the positions are disjointed and maybe that's why it doesn't work. Even if my attempt at solving is overly complicated (and bad), how would I make it work?

Comment: You can't. For each index in `string`, your code is iterating over all of `positions` and then creating a `string2` and appending it to `new_list_strings`. In otherwords you're creating new strings every time the index `i` was equal to one of the positions. This is why you were getting weird permutations of strings in your output.

Comment: Another reason your solution doesn't work is because when you create `string2`, you're concatenating the two slices of the string on either side of *any single given* hyphen character, but this doesn't fix any later characters whose index corresponds to a hyphen. I suggest placing more print statements where you're creating `string2` to see what's happening.

Comment: @tadeufontes see the "what am I doing wrong" section of my answer: I've edited to add more and better print statements to show exactly what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it:

```
list_strings=["A-C-TG--","ATCGTAGC","ATGCGATC","ATGCGGTC"]
new_list_strings=[]
positions=[i for i, letter in enumerate(list_strings[0]) if letter == "-"]

# Hack so I can handle the first pos like the others
positions = [-1] + positions
# positions is now [-1, 1, 3, 6, 7]

for string in list_strings:
    string2 = ''
    for j, pos in enumerate(positions):
        # Get segment between current pos and the previous one
        string2 += string[positions[j-1]+1:pos]
    new_list_strings.append(string2)
```

Comment: This is unnecessarily complicated, the normal accumulator pattern works fine. What is this magic `[-1]`?

Comment: I agree it's not the shortest way to write it, but I'm trying to stick as much as possible to the op's logic, that's all.

Comment: Right, but what I'm saying is that it's entirely possible to use the accumulator pattern without resorting to weird magic numbers and index juggling. See my answer. By "complicated" I didn't mean "long".

Answer (score 1):

[itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) (from the operator library).

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> L=["A-C-TG--","ATCGTAGC","ATGCGATC","ATGCGGTC"]
>>> idx = [i for i,v in enumerate(L[0]) if v != '-']
>>> for item in L:
    print(''.join(itemgetter(*idx)(item)))

    
ACTG
ACTA
AGGA
AGGG
```